# How to toggle "Show standard map in viewport" via maxscript?

Tags: 3dsmax, maxscript

In the slate material editor, I can right click a material and toggle "show Standard Map in Viewport". How can I toggle/set this option of a material programatically from maxscsript?

Answer (score 6):

Simply use the materials `.ShowInViewport` property.

example: `myMaterial.showInViewport = on`

Answer (score 2):

On the Top of the Menu Bar, While You are choosing/Clicking "Material Editor" Button, Left Click That Button for More Than 1 Second, You Will Get another Advanced Option Material Editor you can toggle between this option.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the function showTextureMap,

It works on the material level and the texturemap level:

Example 1: showTextureMap $box001.material On

Example 2: showTextureMap $box001.material $box001.material.diffusemap On

To turn it off, just type Off at the end instead of On